# One-Sided Hypothesis Test with T-Statistic in R?

Tags: r, testing, statistics, normal-distribution

I want to test the following hypothesis in R using a t-statistic and compute the p-value:

Null Hypothesis : mu <= 50

Alternate :       mu > 50

```
data = c(52.7, 53.9, 41.7, 71.5, 47.6, 55.1,
       62.2, 56.5, 33.4, 61.8, 54.3, 50.0, 
       45.3, 63.4, 53.9, 65.5, 66.6, 70.0,
       52.4, 38.6, 46.1, 44.4, 60.7, 56.4);
```

It should be very easy, but I'm not sure how to do it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: More serious, check out http://www.statmethods.net for some basic stats in R. In particular the fourth example of http://www.statmethods.net/stats/ttest.html.

Comment: +1 for the LMGTFY reference @SachaEpskamp

Comment: I realize this should be very easy, but the examples I've found and the sites listed above are all for Ho: mu=50, whereas I need mu<=50. I'm not sure how to indicate that to R.

Comment: take a look at `?t.test` and be sure to read about the arguments `x`, `mu`, and `alternative` ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your `H0` equals: `mu<=50`  the right command is:

```
t.test(data, mu=50, alternative = 'greater')
```

With `alternative` you define `H1`. Consequently it is: `H1: mu > 50`.
The output shows the `p.value`, mean and `t-value`.
That's it.

Answer (score 1):

if the given condition in the question is right then we use the, one sided upper test. i.e.

```
t.test(data, alternative= "greater", mu=50) output = One Sample t-test
```

**data:**

```
data t = 2.1562, df = 23, p-value = 0.02088
```

alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 50
95 percent confidence interval:
 `50.88892`      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x

```
54.33333
```

conclusion is that in this p- value is less  then 0.05 , so we reject null hypothesis.
if in altenative hypothesis is not equal to 100, then we use alternative= "two.sided". 
everything is depend on the condition, sometime in question is already mentioned less or greater.